# django + apache + mod_wsgi + ssl error, hasattr not defined

Tags: python, django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi

Only when I use SSL, apache refuses to start, and I see this error in error.log:

```
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 585, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
```

If I comment out the line `Include extra/httpd-ssl.conf`, then apache will start fine. (but without ssl of course)
I checked the httpd-ssl.conf file, and I think my certificate is correctly set.
And this error does not imply anything. I couldn't find a solution online.

Comment: Is that Anaconda Python or PSF distro?

Comment: Just normal python 3.6 (PSF), on windows, with apache24

Comment: Not 100% sure about Windows, but Python 3.6 on MacOS X from PSF now ships with its own SSL libraries. This makes it impossible to use mod_wsgi with mod_ssl and then use SSL from Python code. This is because Apache will load its SSL libraries from operating system first. This will be incompatible with the SSL libraries Python ships and things will not work. I can only assume Python 3.6 on Windows must ship with its own SSL libraries as well. Try and find out if Python 3.6 on Windows does in fact ship with SSL libraries.

Comment: But I did manage to setup apache2.2 + mod_wsgi + python2.7 + mod_ssl.  I upgraded python and apache, and installed the new mod_wsgi (using pip). So it seems that python2.7 ssl libs and the OS libs were fine. I don't see why it should be a problem with python3.6. And anyway, how is this error (in PIL code, which I actually did not install) relates to the issue?

Comment: Okay, my memory of this bad. I knew it had come up before and you would have found it with a Google search. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939556/nameerror-name-hasattr-is-not-defined-python3-6-django1-11-ubuntu16-17-a So always try searching first.

Comment: Commenting here as well in case it prevents some headaches: in multiple cases Apache throws such errors when in fact the underlying problem is something completely different. Try turning `DEBUG` on in your `settings.py`, and something else might turn up! (In my instance Apache was throwing the `hasattr` error when in reality all I did wrong was to pass an incorrect parameter to a template function in my Django app.)