# Django 2 production image upload results in 500 error

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 2.0.1 within a virtual environment in production mode with Apache 2.4.
Whenever I try to upload an image from Django's admin panel I get a server error 500.
The specific error is

```
[Sat Feb 10 11:37:42.473376 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1311:tid 140525266585472] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/springspree/server/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 587, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/springspree/server/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 587, in __del__
NameError: name 'hasattr' is not defined
```

The virtualhost file is

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerAdmin webdev@springspree.in
        ServerName www.springspree.in:8000

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /var/www/springspree/server/static
        <Directory /var/www/springspree/server/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /var/www/springspree/server/media
        <Directory /var/www/springspree/server/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/springspree/server/springspree>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess django-server python-path=/var/www/springspree/server python-home=/var/www/springspree/server/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django-server
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/springspree/server/springspree/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

The files are in /var/www directory owned by root. I tried uninstalling and installing Pillow but no use.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939556/nameerror-name-hasattr-is-not-defined-python3-6-django1-11-ubuntu16-17-a

Comment: What version of `Pillow` are you using?

Comment: 5.0.0 is the Pillow version